# Populating an array in javascript, what is the difference between those two method?

Tags: javascript, arrays

here is the code of test 1

```
array_one = [];
array_one[1] = 'image1.jpg';
array_one[2] = 'image2.jpg';
array_one[3] = 'image3.jpg';
```

and the code of test 2

```
array_two = ['image1.jpg', 'images2.jpg', 'images3.jpg'];
```

why the first one work... and the other on is not...
in fact i am looking for a solution to populate an array, without having to assign the index.

note : dont talk about the [0] index, i just dont use it...

Comment: Usually you want to start with index `0`, not `1`...

Comment: The second one is valid - that's the way to do it.

Comment: If you want to populate an array without having to assign the index yourself, you could also use `array_one.push('image4.jpg');` if that's what you are talking about... a little vague

Comment: `array_two = ['image1.jpg', ...]` should work..

Comment: You mean `array[1] = ` instead of `array = [1] = `, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
var array_two = ['','image1.jpg', 'images2.jpg', 'images3.jpg'];
alert(array_two);
```

Unless you have the following set and didn't write it in

```
var array_two = new Array();
```

Comment: i dont have : var array_two = new Array(); but i declare the var : var array_two =[] is it the same ?

Comment: No, setting the variable_name = [] does not declare an array without the 'var' before the name. So, you need to declare it with the 'var array_two = new Array();' before populating the array or declare it a var as you populate the array.

Answer (score 2):

The index is zero based.

```
array_two = ['image1.jpg', 'images2.jpg', 'images3.jpg'];
array_two[0]
=> "image1.jpg"
```

and you also have a syntax error, it should be

```
array_one[1] = 'image1.jpg';
=> "image1.jpg"
```